# How to read large sample of images effectively without overloading ram memory?

Tags: python, numpy

While training the classification model I'm passing input image samples as NumPy array but when I try to train large dataset samples I run into memory error. Currently, I've 120 GB size of memory even with this size I run into memory error. I've enclosed code snippet below

```
x_train = np.array([np.array(ndimage.imread(image)) for image in image_list])
x_train = x_train.astype(np.float32)
```

Error traceback:

```
x_train = x_train.astype(np.float32) numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to 
allocate  134. GiB for an array with shape (2512019,82,175,1) and data type float32
```

How can I fix this issue without increasing ram size? is there a better way to read the data like using cache or using protobuf?

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your data?

Comment: It's a folder of classes like cat and dog image folder @AdarshWase

Comment: I didn't understand, show me visually. Edit your question and add any image of your dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would load the first half of the dataset and then train the model on the first half of the dataset and then I would load the 2nd half and train the model on the 2nd part of the dataset. This does not influence the result.

The easiest way to split your dataset is to simply make a 2nd folder with the same structure with 50% of the dataset.

The pseudo-code for that method of training would look like this.:

1. load dataset 1
2. train the model with dataset 1
3. load dataset 2 but into the same variable as the first one to reuse the memory instead of creating a 2nd variable with the first one still in memory
4. train the model with dataset 2

A second option to decrease the memory size of your array you could use `np.float16` instead of `np.float32` but this would result in a more inaccurate model. The difference is data-dependent. So it could be 1-2% or even 5-10% so the only option without losing any accuracy is the option is described above.

**EDIT**

I am going to add the actual code.

```
import cv2 #pip install opencv-python
import os 

part1_of_dataset = os.listdir("Path_to_your_first_dataset")
part2_of_dataset = os.listdir("Path_to_your_second_dataset")

x_train = np.array([cv2.imread(image) for image in part1_of_dataset],dtype=np.float32)
x_train /=255.0
x_train_m = np.mean(x_train,axis=0)
x_train -= x_train_m

model.fit(x_train,y_train) #not the full training code just an example


x_train = np.array([cv2.imread(image) for image in part2_of_dataset],dtype=np.float32)
x_train /=255.0
x_train_m = np.mean(x_train,axis=0)
x_train -= x_train_m

model.fit(x_train,y_train) #not the full training code just an example
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, If I've understand your solution properly it'll create two separate model right ? for each two datasets but I want a single model trained on whole dataset. Using the same variable and training the model again will replace the previous one right?

Comment: No, you use the same model for both training steps and yea using the same variable replaces the previous value

Comment: using the same model you mean starting training from the first model checkpoint for the second dataset?

Comment: Yes but no you reuse the same model but u don't need to save the checkpoint you can simply call the "fit" again it will automatically start where the training of the first dataset ended

Comment: Ok. I haven't tried that before . It works only if variable name is same ? can you direct me to any article or example on this?

Comment: it works even if the values are different names but in your case, you should use the same variable to reuse the memory so that we don't get the memory overflow again

Comment: if the answer helped you out fell free to accept as a answer

Answer (score 0):

This question comes up just as I put the first 2 32GB RAM sticks into my pc today for pretty much the same reason.

At this point it becomes necsessary to handle the data different.

I am not sure what you are using to do the learning. But if its tensorflow you can customize your [input pipeline](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data).

Anyways. It comes down to correctly analyze what you want to do with the data and the capabilities of your environment. If the data is ready to train and you just load it from disk it should not be a problem to only load then train on only a portion of it, then go to the next portion and so on.

You can split this data into multiple files or partially load the data (there are datatypes/fileformats to help with that). You can even optimize this so far that you can read from disk during training and have the next batch ready to go when you need it.